# Accessing USB drive form WinPE prompt

Tags: windows-8, virtualbox, winpe

I am trying to install Windows 8 on virtual box using a bootable WinPE DVD. The image file (.wim) is on the USB stick.
But when I boot from DVD, I cannot find the USB drive.
I need to execute the command

```
d:\imagex.exe /apply e:\imageC_20150528.wim 1 c:\
```

where D - dvd drive and say E - usb drive
But I cannot locate the USB drive from the command prompt.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about solving a programming problem.

Comment: @PeeHaa, I think it is.

Comment: There's a typo in the title: "Accessing USB drive **from** WinPE prompt". Also the virtualbox and windows-8 tags might not be super relevant.

Answer (score 1):

When I use winPE I use DiskPart to determine the drive letter of the USB drive.

```
-Diskpart
-list volume
```

This should display all available drives

Answer (score 1):

If the USB drive was inserted *before* you booted the system into PE, then the USB drive should already be mounted and have a drive letter. If it doesn't then it is likely the drive isn't supported (you might want to change your boot-image/disk to include additional drivers/tools to get access to your usb controller and connected device).

If your USB drive was inserted *after* you booted the system into PE (and your hardware is supported in PE) then I usually can access the disk in the following manner (worked even in XP PE):

- go to commandline and start `diskpart` (following commands are in diskpart):
- issue command: `rescan` <kbd>enter</kbd>
  This 'Locates new disks that might have been added to the computer.'
  Depending on diskpart version (and/or it's `automount` setting) this *can* be enough to automatically mount the file system for a new basic volume when it adds the drive to the system and assigns a drive letter to the volume.
  When it *doesn't*, follow the following 2 steps:
- command: `list disk` <kbd>enter</kbd>
  to see a list of disks and some info (to check the drive was found)
  command: `list volume` <kbd>enter</kbd>
  lists volumes on *all* disks (to find volume number of the USB drive)
- command: `select volume=#` <kbd>enter</kbd>  (where `#`= volume number)
  to select the specified volume and *shift the focus* to it
  command: `assign` <kbd>enter</kbd>
  to assign the *next free letter* to the *current focused volume*
  OR: `assign letter=#` <kbd>enter</kbd> (where `#`= driveletter of choice)

This method usually works for me on *most* hardware.

See also: [Diskpart commandline options on MS Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766465%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Really - you should be using a fairly current version of winPE - 5.1 is what I'm using - which is the version that parallels windows 8.1. I'm switching over to winPE 10 (they changed the numbering to be consistent with Windows)

The reason I bring this us is because you're using imagex - and dism.exe has largely replaced imagex.exe in more current versions of winPE.

If you're just doing this at the command prompt in a generic winPE, you can use `mountvol.exe` (with no parameters) to discover the drive letters that are available. Everything shifts around drive-letter-wise when you're in winPE. So it might not be e: any more.

Also, dism and/or imagex would be on the x: drive - which is the virtual drive that the winPE creates when it boots.